# How to display large number of path element in D3JS

Tags: svg, path, d3.js

I'm displaying all county data in a map with D3js. Basically I'm using the Geo json data for all the counties and create path for each in d3js. (similar to http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/)

The number of path would be around 3000?
Every time, when I use the viewset function to rescale and transform all the path. It takes some time. I feel like that is the reason that slows down my program.

Any better idea about this? like not redraw the path outside screen?

Comment: In this case, the sheer number of elements is most likely the problem. The browser should already optimise based on what's actually visible and what not, so doing that explicitly is unlikely to improve performance. What you can try is to simplify your data so that the complexity of the paths is reduced.

Comment: I have implemented methods in the past when converting data from raw GEO data to KML/SVG to do some optimization by only dropping points. Other times I use a GEO system to reduce the complexity of the polygons before processing.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a good idea to reduce the data complexity itself before displaying it.

Comment: Have you looked into [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson)?  It can significantly reduce the size of the data.  Have at look at this [tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) and here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rHmev/1/) of the large dataset zooming in and out with it.